# Question On Asking A Question About Vague Protocol Description

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to request a link to explanatory tutorials ?

My next task is to add USB capability to our device. (The hardware is, purportedly, already in place.)

Looking on the internet, this pretty much sums up my problem...

"...*We suggest 94 pdf files related to Usb Protocol Tutorial.*..." [Found Here](http://pdfsb.com/usb+protocol+tutorial)

I spent 10 hours reading the 50+ page Family Reference manual USB module Chapter on this device. (It's a PIC24.)

There is, supposedly, a library already written to do this, and it is (again, supposedly) an easy *drop and compile* process. I'm still searching for such a library. The examples I've found are hardly commented the way that I would call, well, whatever.

The microchip website's forums are sometimes stupendously helpful with real bugs, but the most common experience tends to be openly hostile antagonism from those who have the knowledge and seem to delight with exuberant glee when they observe someone trying to learn how the chip works.

From reading the fifty-something page Family Reference Manual chapter, my guess at the moment is that these 94 documents can be reduced down to about a dozen rules which the firmware designer in an embedded system needs to know.

So now, how do I find that 12 rule simplified version ?

Is there a place to ask for links to more complete, and less highly focused, broadly based tutorials ?

(Mods, please feel free to move this to meta.stackoverflow if this belongs elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Why ask for a link to tutorials, instead of saying you'd like some guidance on how to proceed and letting those in a position to help offer help as they see fit?  Answers that are just links are discouraged for a variety of reasons.

By all means, include a summary of your efforts to date and why they couldn't work.

That said, your research efforts to date, while seemingly sizable, don't seem particularly well placed -- a simple google search for "pic24 usb stack" yields a ton of great hits, seemingly much more useful than the Family Reference Manual and your pointer to 94 pdfs.  You might want to run down that path before posting your question, and your question might be much more useful to your efforts as a result.

Implementation of a USB stack is fairly advanced, but achievable by a patient person fairly experienced with the platform.